# How do you accurately set the offset of an axisLabel in CorePlot?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

Problem Statement:

A bar plot in created with CorePlot has a Y-axis that features a dynamic range. The minimum value of this range is presumed to be <= 0. The maximum value of the range is presumed to be > 0.

The bar plot features custom X-axis labels which have an offset to distance themselves from the 0 line of the Y-axis. (`label.offset`)

However, because the exact location of the 0 line may change during runtime, a static value to offset the X-axis labels is not sufficient.

Question:

What is the appropriate way to accurately set the offset of Axis labels, when axis parameters change at runtime?

Screenshot attached to show problem. Labels should be below the ($200,000) line, but because the top end value is dynamic, they move up and down.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZURIB.png

Answer (score 0):

From the linked picture, it doesn't look like you're drawing the axis line. Use axis constraints to hold the x-axis at the bottom of the plot area. If you do want to draw an axis line, e.g., at `y = 0`, add a second x-axis. Use one to draw the axis line and the other to position the labels. Set all of the line style properties of the second axis to `nil` so it doesn't draw any lines and use constraints to hold it at the bottom of the plot area.